Problem with authentication popup and new outlook
Im using the Teams js authentication module.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40microsoft/teams-js/microsoftteams.authentication?view=msteams-client-js-1.13.1&viewFallbackFrom=msteams-client-js-latest
in the new Outlook client its opening in an external browser instead of like in Teams (web/desktop/mobile), M365 app (web/desktop), Old Outlook (Web/Desktop) it opens up in a little popup inside the application.
We have this solution to authenticate a user in a tab with different IDP's
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad?tabs=teamsjs-v2
Anyone has a working solution NOT opening new outlook in another browser but in the desktop application as the rest of the suite?
This was an issue with new teams for a short while but it has been "fixed".
Expected the authentication url not opening in an external browser, tried different authentication flows from microsoft documentation.

Could you please share some screen shots for your behavior in old and new Outlook client?

Hi, sorry for late response. I have the exact problem as https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/teams-app-won-t-authenticate-in-new-outlook/m-p/4148762
